# apache mod_jk loadbalancing glassfish cluster instances issue

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, glassfish, mod-jk

I have a Java EE6 EAR application deployed on an Open Source GlassFish v3.1 server running on a Windows 2003 R2 Server on 2 clusters with 2 instances each. To load balance the work load, I am using an apache http server with mod_jk. When I look at the jk status page however I see that the work is being distributed to only one of the instances in each cluster even though all four have the same lbfactor of 1. Any ideas?

[image: JK Status page snapshot]

Here is my workers.properties config:

```
worker.list=loadbalancerLocal,status

worker.status.type=status

worker.ViewerLocalInstance1.type=ajp13
worker.ViewerLocalInstance1.host=localhost
worker.ViewerLocalInstance1.port=8109
worker.ViewerLocalInstance1.lbfactor=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance1.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance1.socket_timeout=1000


worker.ViewerLocalInstance2.type=ajp13
worker.ViewerLocalInstance2.host=localhost
worker.ViewerLocalInstance2.port=8209
worker.ViewerLocalInstance2.lbfactor=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance2.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance2.socket_timeout=1000

worker.ViewerLocalInstance3.type=ajp13
worker.ViewerLocalInstance3.host=localhost
worker.ViewerLocalInstance3.port=8309
worker.ViewerLocalInstance3.lbfactor=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance3.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance3.socket_timeout=1000

worker.ViewerLocalInstance4.type=ajp13
worker.ViewerLocalInstance4.host=localhost
worker.ViewerLocalInstance4.port=8409
worker.ViewerLocalInstance4.lbfactor=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance4.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ViewerLocalInstance4.socket_timeout=1000

worker.loadbalancerLocal.type=lb
worker.loadbalancerLocal.sticky_session=True
worker.loadbalancerLocal.balance_workers=ViewerLocalInstance1,ViewerLocalInstance2,ViewerLocalInstance3,ViewerLocalInstance4
```

Here is my httpd config for mod_jk

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel info
# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

JkMount /Viewer/* loadbalancerLocal
JkMount /Viewer loadbalancerLocal
JkMount /jkstatus/* status
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the sticky session turned on.  Try turning it off.  You may need to unset jvmRoute too if you have set it.